# Button Click on Page Load Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code that i would like to execute when the user loads the page. The code is currently for a update button that the user clicks and updates some values on the webpage. The user would like to do this without having to click on the update button.

```
  using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProductionData", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   { 

       <h3>Date :</h3>   <input type="text" id="dp" name="dp" />

       <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
   }
```

I have tried looking at jquery. I am wondering if this is possible inside razor.

Comment: "When the user loads the page"? Why don't you just execute the code before the page loads if you know it should always execute?

Comment: I have tried to do this in the controller by calling the method UpdateProductionData. Is it possible to do the update button in razor?

Comment: So you want to submit the form on page load?

Comment: When exactly do you want to submit this form? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Yes or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov When the page initial loads

Comment: But what's the point of loading a page that will immediately leave? Because that's what will happen when you submit the form. I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Why not tell us your original requirement? Also there's some `dp` input field inside this form. Don't you care about the value from this field?

Comment: Move the code out from within `UpdateProductionData` into a separate method, then just call that from within the Controller which is managing the page with the form.